# phantomjs proxy in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, phantomjs

i've been trying to get phantomjs running over a proxy in nodejs

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var url = 'http://ipecho.net/';

phantom.create({parameters: {proxy:'196.11.90.57:8080'}},function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open(url, function (status) {
      console.log("opened page? ", status);
        page.evaluate(function () { return document; }, function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          ph.exit();
        });
    });
  });
}, {
    dnodeOpts: {weak: false}
});
```

executing this with phantomjs-node i find that the ip on the ipecho page is my local ip without proxy....

my goal is to download a page via proxy and evaluate the js on the page in order to see the final format.

Any ideas????

greetz, 
Linus

Comment: Have you checked here: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/wiki  for correct format of passing command-line switches to PhantomJS? An example there goes like `phantom.create("--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", function(ph){ /**/ })